# Implementing Kalman Filter with latitude and longitude

Tags: java, filtering, kalman-filter

I am from non mathematics background and need some help in implementing kalman filter in my java application.
Basically, I get inputs from various sensors of a particular entity on map. The inputs are the location in latitude and longitude terms along with its accuracy.
Now based on several inputs that I received for the same entity, I need to predict the accurate position of the entity on the map. Note that I don't have to track it continuously.

How do I provide inputs of lat,long and accuracy to kalman filter such that I get a fused predicted value as an output from which lat&long can be obtained to plot the same back on map?

Answer (score 2):

As you dont provide much information on the problem, I will present a simple solution with only a latitude/longitude/accuracy:

I would start by defining the Kalman filter dynamics as a random walk with velocity having the random noise

```
x = [rx, ry, vx, vy],
```

where x is the state of the Kalman filter. Now the prediction part of the model becomes

```
x_{k+1} = A*x_k + Q,
```

where

```
A = [1, 0, dt, 0;0, 1, 0, dt;0, 0, 1, 0;0, 0, 0, 1]
```

and Q can be found on page 56 of [Applied Stochastic Differential
Equations](http://becs.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/course_s2014/sde_course_booklet.pdf)

For applying the observation on lat/lon/accuracy, I would start by converting the WGS84 coordinates to local [ENU coordinates](http://dougaloogle.com/Offshore%20Project%20Coordinators%20Manual/main_pages/general/cm_dp_geodetics.htm) (metric). This makes the system more robust and easier to interpret.

The update becomes

```
y = H*x + R,
```

where y is the observation of the position [rx, ry] and

```
H = [1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0]
```

and you use your accuracy in observation noise:

```
R = diag([accuracyx, accuracy]),
```

where accuracy is now the variance of the position.

This is a standard way to do this kind of 2D tracking. As you only use lat/lon/accuracy the results might not be as accurate as you want.

Now you can apply the above system to produce the Kalman predict and update methods

Comment: I don't see the definition of Q on p56 of the book you link to. Am I missing something?